# Удаление узла со значением атрибута

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Нужно удалить узел Zakaz с атрибутом ZakazID="1".
Задаю переменную с XML документом:

```
DECLARE @docxml xml;
SET @docxml='<Root>
                <Shop>
                <Items>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="1" ZakazName="Tablets1" ZakazCategory="A">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="650"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма1
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма2
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets1</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="2" ZakazName="Tablets2" ZakazCategory="B">
                        <Price nom="DOL" pnom="150"/>
                        <Firms lang="английский">
                            <Firma>
                            Firma1
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Firma1
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets2</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                    <Zakaz ZakazID="3" ZakazName="Tablets3" ZakazCategory="C">
                        <Price nom="RUB" pnom="300"/>
                        <Firms lang="русский">
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма3
                            </Firma>
                            <Firma>
                            Фирма4
                            </Firma>
                        </Firms>
                        <Features>
                        <Description>Описание товара Tablets3</Description>
                        </Features>
                    </Zakaz>
                </Items>
                </Shop>
            </Root>';
SET @docxml.modify ('delete /Root/Shop/Zakaz [@ZakazID="2"]')
SELECT @docxml;
```

Узел не удаляется.

Comment: В пути пропущен элемент `Items`

Comment: Точно, спасибо!